# AWS Beanstalk NodeJS app - what happens when I save to file system?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, filesystems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an app that currently saves some data as a file to file system. On self-hosted server it saves it to a disk. When I deploy it to AWS Beanstalk service where will this file end up? Does AWS use persistent or ephemereal file system?

My use case is very simple and I don't want to bother with setting up S3 storage, is it possible to just leave it be? Can I access the file system somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underneath the beanstalk wrapper, there are ec2 instances, which are running your code. So if you use file system storage, the file will be saved in on the disk/attached volume. Volume data are persistent and you can ssh into the ec2 instance to find your saved file.